# Arduino StackArray not global

Tags: c, arduino, stack

I'm coding a project where I read a byte of serial data, convert it to binary and then print it out to Serial.  Currently, I'm using a stack to store the binary.  However, when I push the binary numbers to the stack, they appear to be pushed in the method I call push() in, but I cannot pop ints from that array outside of that method because there are no elements to pop.  Why, and are there any ways to resolve this problem.  I thought stacks were reference variables.

```
void convertToBinary(byte number, StackArray<int> binaryList){
while(number > 0){
    int rem = number % 2;
    binaryList.push(rem);
    number /= 2; 
    }
}
```

It pushes this seemingly fine.  However when I try to pop it in another method in which I pass the stack to be popped, no elements are there to be popped.

```
void printToLED(StackArray<int> list){
  //digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  while(!list.isEmpty()){
    int ledState = list.pop();
    //Serial.println(ledState);
    if(ledState == 1){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);    
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  
    }
    delay(1000);
    transitionFlash();
  }
}
```

Since in the setup I specified serial as the stack printer, it gives me this message when I try to pop an element from the stack.

```
STACK: can't pop item from stack: stack is empty.
```

EDIT(Full example):

```
#include <StackArray.h>
StackArray<int> binary;
int ledPin = 13;
byte data = 0;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  binary.setPrinter(Serial);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void transitionFlash(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
  delay(50);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
  delay(50);
  }
}

void convertToBinary(byte number, StackArray<int> binaryList){
  while(number > 0){
    int rem = number % 2;
    binaryList.push(rem);
    number /= 2; 
  }
}

void printToLED(StackArray<int> list){
  while(!list.isEmpty()){
    int ledState = list.pop();
    if(ledState == 1){
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);    
    }
    else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  
    }
    delay(1000);
    transitionFlash();
  }
}

void blink(int times, int duration){
  for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    delay(duration);
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
    delay(duration);
  }
}

void loop() {
  while(Serial.available()){
    data = Serial.read();
    convertToBinary(data, binary);
    printToLED(binary);
    blink(10, 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this.  In order to pass it as a reference variable, I need to add an ampersand to the front, to notify C that it is in fact a reference variable.

Comment: Could you post the example?